# Which web framework to use that can integrate well with existing Desktop app?

Tags: frameworks, web, web-frameworks

We currently have a client/server Desktop Java application that is used in clinics to manage patient charts (text, graphcs, images, etc). It is a highly interactive application.

We're now trying to gradually move towards the web, First, we want to implement a new feature that can be accessed from an embedded browser within the Java client. 
1. The embedded browser should be able to communicate to the Java client. 
2. We should to be able to reuse most of our existing Java classes on the server side 
3. The framework should allow us to create rich user experience (e.g user should be able to draw on diagrams, or drag and drop items, etc, and not experience too much delay).

How can I figure out whether a certain web framework will satisfy all the above criteria? Do we have to stick to Java web frameworks, or can we easily venture into Ruby or PHP related frameworks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's a big question; impossible to answer with a simple "yes/no".

Personally, I'm a fan of Java ... and it sounds like you already have Java expertise in-house.

I would looke at Tomcat (a relatively simple servlet container) and JBoss (a full-fledged Java EE application, which, IMHO, is every bit as robust as expensive application servers like WebLogic and WebSphere).

To the extent "web applications" are a new world for you, I would also look at IIS and .Net.

Based on your experience and your application, I would *not* necessarily look at Ruby or PHP before you've had a chance to consider JSP, Java web services vs. C#/ADO.Net first.

IMHO...

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting question, and I'd like to see other answers, too. For myself, a few years back I was building such an application and it had different modules for different functional areas - all of them on the web. The main modules were:

1. JavaWS based stand alone application - working on 1 computer attached to a scanner - from which scanned reports and images were uploaded to the server
2. Java applet spanning the whole web page (100% width/height) - for drag and drops, patient body part pictorial reviews, etc.
3. Java applet with a unique tree implementation to generate EHR's - with ICD numbers and CPT codes downloaded from a server and cached on local machine.
4. Desktop (again, java-6) to fire up web browsers to view the reports in Html (Java Html editors are not too kind with CSS).
5. Access levels were maintained on server database (different for the doctors, office manager, assistants, nurses and patients (for portals on appointments and data updates))

In summary, I don't think that a single application can meet all the needs for such a system. But then, I am interested in others' opinions, too.